# Why does component rerender forces webpage to reset scroll position?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm developing a personal blog using Next.js. I fetch posts from my API based on a page query for a pagination, then loop through the items like that:

```js
let content = (
    <ul>
    {props.posts.map((post) => {
        return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
    })}
    </ul>
);
```

```
return (
<div className="container">
    <div className="posts">{content}</div>
</div>
);
```

This works as expected. When I go on a next page, I get new posts and the page stays at the same scroll position.

But when I make the posts a component:

```
return (
<div className="container">
    <Posts props={props} />
</div>
);
```

```
export const Posts = ({ props }) => {
  return (
    <ul>
      {props.posts.map((post) => {
        return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Now when I click on a next page, the Posts component gets rerendered, and new posts get displayed, but the scroll position is reset and even though I before scrolled to bottom, I'm now at the top of the page.

Why does this happen? Does it happen because the entire UI is forced to rerender, essentially resetting the scroll position? How can I maintain the scroll position?

Thanks and sorry for the dumb question, started with React and Next.js not too long ago

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if this is the case, but there's a couple of thing I see that are a bit weird.

First, don't pass your props like that. That's bad. props is just a parameter name that's standardized for React developers to call the stuff you pass to your components. Pass your props like this instead

```
const { posts } = props;
return (
  <div className="container">
    <Posts posts={posts} />
  </div>
);
```

And on your child component you can destructure your component parameters to get out the value you actually need:

```
const Posts = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div className="posts">
      <ul>
        {posts.map((post) => {
          return <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>;
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also, I notice that the working example has `<div className="posts">` that wraps your `<ul>`. I've wrapped it around your `<ul>` in your `Posts` component. Try it out and see if it works.

Lastly, if your parent component rerenders multiple times, and you don't want your child component to rerender, you can memoize your child component, so they only rerender when their props change. This is also why you don't wanna pass all your props down, only the values you actually need.

To prevent uneccessary rerenders you can wrap your component with a `React.memo` like so:

```
export default React.memo(Posts);
```

This way since Posts only takes `posts` as its props, if the value of `posts` doesn't change, your `Post` component will not rerender, and hopefully..? things would work as how you want them to.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I tried memo, messed around a bit - nothing helped. But I figured out, that the main problem, why the scroll position is not restored/maintained is probably due to use of getServerSideProps and next-i18next module